# Strategy for Push notifications on Safari

Tags: ios, websocket, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on implementing a PWA which needs to send push notifications, we are looking at a solution for sending push notifications to browsers running on ios(We are using Firebase(FCM) for everything else.) What would be a good strategy to make push notifications on all platforms including ios?

We are looking at sniffing the user-agent and use FCM for non-ios users, switch to websockets for ios users. We aren't sure how viable this approach is gonna be. Any suggestions on this approach or a better alternative would be of great help!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can treat Safari like an APNS device: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through the docs mentioned above. Do you happen to know if this would work with other browsers on iOS the way it works with Safari(Chrome, Firefox)?

Comment: "In OS X v10.9 and later, you can dispatch Safari Push Notifications from your web server directly to OS X users by using the Apple Push Notification service (APNs)." That documentation is specific to desktop. As I understand it mobile Safari doesn't support push notifications.

Comment: @Gunner Just for future reference, other browsers on iOS are just reskinned versions of Safari. The "core" (layout engine, js engine, etc.) cannot be changed by iOS developers, so if it behaves a certain way in Safari, it will work the same way in those browsers.

Comment: No, it would not work the same way on Safari as other browsers. Other browsers would use WebPush and ServiceWorkers to accomplish push notifications, while Safari would behave much more similar to an iPhone with regards to it being treated as an APNS device.

Comment: @BrentHronik The linked dev guide is ambiguous at best, it does not say for sure anywhere that one could send push notifications to safari on ios.

Comment: After having the same requirement and some research, as of today it is not possible to send notifications to Safari on ios or to any other browser on ios. APNS too can't help you here, APNS will be handy if you are looking at safari on OSX, however, a chrome on OSX can take notifications from GCM

Comment: @Gunner what did you end up using? I'm having the same issue, and my app won't even load on iOS because of the service worker. is there a way to exclude that service worker on iOS ?