# Angular site won't open on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

I simply cannot figure out what the problem is.

I have a very simple website made in angular that runs perfectly fine on the desktop (Chrome) but simply shows a blank page on my mobile (iPhone 6).

I have tried emulating it locally and online without any issues. I have run count less test from all different sites and they don't seem to find any issues.

The website is: https://admin.marcrasmussen.dk

I know this is fairly unusual but I have attempted to fix this for the past 5 hours. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: On OS X (Safari), I'm getting a 404 on the resource `https://admin.marcrasmussen.dk/vendor/angular-ui-router.js.map`. The page itself is loading, however.

Comment: @matthewninja That is very odd the only angular-ui-router file i load is: <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this code in your `App.js`:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission().then(...).catch(...);
```

[Firebase client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) uses [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) that [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) by some browsers.

You can add the browser's support checking, for example:

```
if (!window.Notification && !window.webkitNotifications) {
    return;
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission().then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to send push notifications from your web app to your phone?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen seems like it's not possible yet. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840344/2570353) with the discussion in the comments and [this article](https://onesignal.com/blog/when-will-web-push-be-supported-in-ios/).

Answer (score 5):

This is what i found debuggin your site.

[image: CONSOLE]

is an issue of firebase-messagin.js check if for an update to support safari for ios. i found this other question on SO who asking similar issues .
[Firebase on iPad's Safari; Can't find variable: Notification Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41494099/8303694)

what recocomends is to turn off the notification prompt when detect the browser, to avoid the js crash.

Comment: is there no way to send push notifications through firebase to your phone from your webapp?

Comment: you may need APNS(Apple Push Notifications), to work on iOS safari.  distinguish browser and use one or another (PN push notifications for chrome or firefox)